# Filter string by non alphanumeric character

Tags: powerbi, dax

There is a field where the value is a colon delimited string with key:value pairs.

It has been filtered by a key such that the string, in DAX, becomes:

`:value;restofstring`

Trying to filter on the colon, :, or the semicolon, ;, throws an error.

What is the proper way to extract just the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PATHITEM to get at values in delimited fields.

For example, PATHITEM( SUBSTITUTE( "key:value", ":", "|"), 1) will return "key".

Changing it to PATHITEM( SUBSTITUTE( "key:value", ":", "|"), 2) will return "value".

The core pattern is PATHITEM( SUBSTITUTE( yourdelimitedfield, yourdelimiterwithqutoes, "|"), yourposition).